# Why does this exists prematurely with a Sigill signal?

Tags: c++, class, object

I have a problem in which I have to return the name of a winner in a fight between two fighters.
The class for fighter is as follows:

```
class Fighter
{
private:
std::string name;

int health;

int damagePerAttack;

public:
Fighter(std::string name, int health, int damagePerAttack)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->health = health;
    this->damagePerAttack = damagePerAttack;
}

~Fighter() { };

std::string getName()
{
    return name;
}

int getHealth()
{
    return health;
}

int getDamagePerAttack()
{
    return damagePerAttack;
}

void setHealth(int value)
{
    health = value;
}
};
```

I wrote a function that should return the name of the winner.

```
  std::string declareWinner(Fighter* fighter1, Fighter* fighter2, 
  std::string firstAttacker)
  {
     // Your code goes here. Have fun!
    if(firstAttacker==fighter1->getName())
    {
      while(fighter1->getHealth()!=0&&fighter2->getHealth()!=0)
      {
        fighter2->setHealth(fighter2->getHealth()-fighter1->getDamagePerAttack());
        if(fighter2->getHealth()<=0)
        {
          return fighter1->getName();
        }
        fighter1->setHealth(fighter1->getHealth()-fighter2->getDamagePerAttack());
        if(fighter1->getHealth()<=0)
        {
          return fighter2->getName();
        }
      }
    }
    else if(firstAttacker==fighter2->getName())
    {
      while(fighter1->getHealth()!=0&&fighter2->getHealth()!=0)
      {
        fighter1->setHealth(fighter1->getHealth()-fighter2->getDamagePerAttack());
        if(fighter1->getHealth()<=0)
        {
          return fighter2->getName();
        }
        fighter2->setHealth(fighter2->getHealth()-fighter1->getDamagePerAttack());
        if(fighter2->getHealth()<=0)
        {
          return fighter1->getName();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This satisfies all my needs, but it throws SIGILL signal, and i do not know what i did wrong. How should I deal with it?

Comment: How do you know it crashes in declareWinner and not somewhere else?

Comment: Apart from checking the fighters for NULL-Pointers, make sure that you return a string in all cases of calling declareWinner().

Comment: @mnistic I do not know where it crashes , i just know it throws that sigill signal. I'm trying to solve this problem on codewars, so it just shows me that signal. I.ve tried to put it in codeblocks to run too , and for some simple examples it works well.

Comment: Step 1: Run it under a debugger. Look at a stacktrace when it crashes. Verify it dies where/when you think it does. Step 2: step through the execution in the debugger, observe state, ensure it is what you expect at each step.   In short: debug the problem.

Comment: @Gerriet i am ensured that the pointers are not NULL, and why should i return a string in all cases? I mean ,  i am ensured that the firstAttacker is in the tests

Comment: From a design standpoint, setHealth() should be replaced by changeHealthBy(). Also instead of multiple calls of getHealth()<=0 you could do something like bool hasLost().

Comment: I can see no code that ensures the pointers are not NULL. Also, program defensively, so make all assumptions explicit (e.g. that one of the fighters has the name that you give).

Comment: @Gerriet , as i said before , i cant change the name of the classes or functions, even though i would like to name them differently. And the code doesnt ensures me that the pointers are not NULL but the problem does. I'll try and check it though.

Comment: @JesperJuhl i have done that , and for something like this                  
    `Fighter fighter1("Jerry", 30, 3);
    Fighter fighter2("Harald", 20, 5);
 cout<<declareWinner(&fighter1, &fighter2, "Jerry"); `                                             it doesnt throw sigill

Comment: What if firstAttacker name is different from both fighter1's and fighter2's? That would result in not returning std::string and can cause SIGILL. Doesn't your compiler warn on return value for that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some conditions, it is possible that function runs to the end and exits without returning a value, that corrupts stack and can lead to SIGILL. As a safe measure you can, for example, add return statement to the end of function.

```
std::string declareWinner(Fighter* fighter1, Fighter* fighter2, 
    std::string firstAttacker)
{
    // Your code goes here. Have fun!
        if(firstAttacker==fighter1->getName())
        {
          while(fighter1->getHealth()!=0&&fighter2->getHealth()!=0)
          {
            fighter2->setHealth(fighter2->getHealth()-fighter1->getDamagePerAttack());
            if(fighter2->getHealth()<=0)
            {
              return fighter1->getName();
            }
            fighter1->setHealth(fighter1->getHealth()-fighter2->getDamagePerAttack());
            if(fighter1->getHealth()<=0)
            {
              return fighter2->getName();
            }
          }
        }
        else if(firstAttacker==fighter2->getName())
        {
          while(fighter1->getHealth()!=0&&fighter2->getHealth()!=0)
          {
            fighter1->setHealth(fighter1->getHealth()-fighter2->getDamagePerAttack());
            if(fighter1->getHealth()<=0)
            {
              return fighter2->getName();
            }
            fighter2->setHealth(fighter2->getHealth()-fighter1->getDamagePerAttack());
            if(fighter2->getHealth()<=0)
            {
              return fighter1->getName();
            }
          }
        }
        return "No winner";   <= Add before exiting function
}
```

I also noticed there's a redundancy  and possible logical errors in code. 
I would rewrite it like this (without changing function signature):

```
std::string declareWinner(Fighter* fighter1, Fighter* fighter2, 
      std::string firstAttacker)
{ 
    Fighter *first;
    Fighter *second;
    if(firstAttacker == fighter1->getName()) {
        first = fighter2;
        second = fighter1;
    } else if (firstAttacker == fighter2->getName()) {
        first = fighter1;
        second = fighter2;
    } else {
        // Bad call parameters
        return "Bad call"; // Throw exception maybe?
    }
    // Simulating fighting
    do {
        std::swap(second,first);
        second->setHealth(second->getHealth() - first->getDamagePerAttack()); 
    } while (second->getHealth() > 0);
    return first->getName(); 

}
```

Comment: I understand your point in adding a return statement at the end, i would've used it if i haven't been sure about the fact that one of the `if` nor `else if`  statements are correct. But , i tried your function and it works and doesnt throw that signal anymore. I am sure it had nothing to do with the fact that the firstAttacker could be different than the names of the fighters, because the tests in the problem ensured me that the firstAttacker is one of the fighters.

Comment: There is also a problem with while condition, which could exit prematurely and not return anything. Should use parenthesis: while((fighter1->getHealth()!=0)&&(fighter2->getHealth()!=0)). But the point is your if conditions don't cover all possible cases, you should always use elses or other guards against premature return from function. Your compiler should give you a warning on that as well.